# Invalid SQL statement with CallableStatement during Stored proc call

Tags: java, sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have below code to call a stored procedure with certain parameters.

However it fails on `callableStatement.execute();` with the error:

`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement`

```
public void setContext(String userId, String someId, List<String> accountsList) {
        List<SqlParameter> parameters = Collections.singletonList(new SqlInOutParameter("output", Types.VARCHAR));
        log.info("executing stored procedure with user id: {}", userId);
        Map<String, Object> t =  defaultTemplate.call(connection -> {
            CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("STORED_PROC(?, ?, ?, ?)");
            callableStatement.setString(1, userId);
            callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);
            callableStatement.setString(3, someId);
            OracleConnection oracleConnection = connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class);
            Array array = oracleConnection.createOracleArray("SOME_TYPE", accountsList.toArray());
            callableStatement.setArray(4, array);
            callableStatement.execute();
            return callableStatement;
        }, parameters);
        log.info("Status of the stored procedure: {}", t.get("status_output"));
 }
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: check for correct statement below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("STORED_PROC(?, ?, ?, ?)");
```

Put `{}` around the argument.And add call before the statement.Like below:

```
CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call STORED_PROC(?, ?, ?, ?)}");
```

Comment: Yup,I missed the 'call keyword'.This one is correct.

Comment: @Plainsage provide your stored procedure so we can have e better insight.

Comment: @Ergi Nushi stored_proc(userId in varchar2, sid in out varchar2, someId in varchar2, v_acct_list in some_type, v_keep_forever in char default 'N');
this is the stored proc signature

Answer (score 2):

Can you just write `call` statement when calling your procedure

```
CallableStatement callableStatement = connection.prepareCall("{call STORED_PROC(?, ?, ?, ?)}");
```